# How to surround a line with parentheses in IntelliJ IdeaVim?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, ideavim, surround

IntelliJ IdeaVim supports vim-surround features now. But how can I quickly surround a line with parentheses in IntelliJ using IdeaVim? I can do this using `yss)` or `yssb` in Vim using the surround plugin. Currently I have to use `^` to go the beginning of the current line, and then use `ys$)` to surround it with parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed IdeaVim 2.2.0. `yss` commands are now working correctly if you upgrade to this version

see [this discussion](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1551/Surround-line-surround-not-working#focus=Comments-27-6973530.0-0)

Comment: needs IntelliJ 2023.1

Answer (score 1):

use vim  surround
surround
Setup: set surround
Emulates vim-surround
Commands: ys, cs, ds, S
see https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/wiki/Emulated-plugins

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, the asker is using surround